# Cannot print out p-value with scientific notation

Tags: python

I cannot print out correct p-value of [proportion z-test](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.proportion.proportions_ztest.html) in python

```
from statsmodels.stats.proportion import proportions_ztest
from decimal import Decimal
count = 6726
nobs = 592458
value = 0.6407
stat, pval = proportions_ztest(count, nobs, value)
print('p-value =','{:.20e}'.format(Decimal(pval)))
```

it prints out `p-value = 0.00000000000000000000e+20`
which I think it's Zero

I used another program to calculate the p-value, it is `2.22e-16` which is `0.000000000000000222`
How can I print out `2.22e-16` in python?

Comment: What is `proportions_ztest`?

Comment: I added the link in the post

Comment: `proportions_ztest` is returning a p-value of 0. No adjustment to your printing logic will change that.

Comment: P-value is impossible to be zero mathematically

Comment: That makes no difference to a floating-point implementation, which can return 0 just fine for a computation for which the correct value in real-number arithmetic would not be 0.

Comment: i see. any suggestion of possible ways that I can print out real number ?

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/ - you are asking how to print `2.22e-16` but your library returns `0.0e+20`. You can not print `2.22e-16` if your variable contains `0.0000000000e+20`. Which _other_ software provided you with your 2.22e-16 result? What precision does it use? What other parameters went into the calculation? Which default were used? Are you sure the implementation is 100% equivalent? Do they reutrn identical values for the examples given at above url?

Answer (score 0):

Unable to reproduce the printing problem - if your result has `2.22e-16` in it - you would be able to print it with:

```
from decimal import Decimal 

whatever = 2.22e-16
print('{:.20e}'.format(Decimal(whatever)))
```

Output:

```
2.22000000000000008179e-16
```

---

Even if you use the (lower-resolution) float set to `2.22e-16` you get an output different to what you observerd (`0.00000000000000000000e+20`):

```
# just using floats
whatever = 2.22e-16 
print('{:.20e}'.format(whatever ))
```

Output:

```
# different from "input" due to float representation error
p-value = 2.21999999999999997153e-20
```

I first thought you might need to adapt the precision, but python does it automatically for you when you create the Decimal() from the number: See `getcontext().prec` [Doku](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html)

---

The [proportions_ztest](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.proportion.proportions_ztest.html) you use returns a float - if it is printed as `0.00000000000000000000e+20` then that is, what was returned from [proportions_ztest](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.proportion.proportions_ztest.html) - if you are not happy with this result, you need to look for some other kind of library that does what you want and internally uses some higher precision.